# Using reflection to get rid of the first two parameters in the function?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following code. Is it possible to use reflection to get rid of the first two parameters since the information can be found in the `Action assign` (Or Expression), which will always have the form of `b.P... = a.P...`?

```
class A { .... }; var a = new A { P1 = .... } // class A and B are totally different clas
class B { .... }; var b = new B { P1 = .... } // But they have some properties with the same names
....
AssignAndDoSth(a.P1, b.P1, () => b.P1 = a.P1);

private void AssignAndDoSth<T>(T curr, T prev, Action assign) // assign can be Expression
{
   if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(curr, prev))
   {
       assign();
       Do(prev);
       ....
   }
}
```

Comment: Then why not get rid of both T curr and T prev?

Comment: Why do you want to go down the dark path of reflection? What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: You could use `Expression<Func<T>>` as type for both curr and prev and create a new expression tree for the assignment, compile and execute that.

Comment: @Karthik Good point. I've updated the question.

Comment: @dcastro It will be easier for users to use the function. And no redundant information is needed in the function.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 But it also would require that users of the function provide a lambda in a very particular way (having the expression be just a single assignment) and violating that expectation would make the code not work.  However the API of the method doesn't force you to do that, nor does it really even imply that you *should* be doing that.  It forces you to rely on documentation alone, which hampers usability for people not familiar with the type.

Comment: @Servy The Lambda/Expression is required in the format (usually) anyway so users already need to follow the documentation.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 Currently it's just "execute this method if these two values are the same".  You may want to assign one value to the other, but if the user doesn't do that, the method doesn't break down at a core level and fail to operate.  It *would* break down at a core level if it relied on actually inspecting the body of the method in the manor you've described.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer would be "I strongly advise against it"; in reality, this is actually an instance method of a compiler-generated capture class; so you would need to deconstruct the IL of the target method, and evaluate that IL against the fields of the target instance. Not good. What that actually looks like is something like:

```
var ctx = new SomeType();
ctx.a = new A { P1 = .... };
ctx.b = new B { P1 = .... };
AssignAndDoSth(a.P1, b.P1, new Action(ctx.SomeMethod));
...
class SomeType {
    public A a;
    public B b;
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        b.P1 = a.P1;
    }
}
```

The other approach would be to refactor to an `Expression<Action>` - but that doesn't change the work involved *much* - it just presents a more friendly API (relatively speaking).

Either way, all that inspection will have a non-trivial performance cost.

Comment: I'm with Marc here, technically its doable. But this is actually much more messy if you can use an extremely simple expression it would be easier, e.g. ()=>x (then it's just read the field reference starting at byte 2 of the action). But the equality and the fact that if you use local variables vs a static reference and if the equal changes what it does based on the type (equal on decimal generates a different expression than equal on int for instance), means that it gets messy fast. Getting the name of that field will be relatively cheap, getting its value will be slow.

Comment: The function will be called in UI event handlers so the performance is not a concern. Yes the function can have Expression instead of Action as parameter type.

Answer (score 0):

An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator, but can contain operator ==

```
  static void AssignAndDoSomething<T>(T curr, T prev, Expression<Func<bool>> assign)
  {
    var logExpr = assign.Body as System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression;
    //output rid of the first parameter
    Console.WriteLine(logExpr.Left);
    //output rid of the second parameter
    Console.WriteLine(logExpr.Right);
    //assign first parameter
    Expression.Lambda<Action>(Expression.Assign(logExpr.Left, Expression.Constant(curr))).Compile()();
    //assign second parameter
    Expression.Lambda<Action>(Expression.Assign(logExpr.Right, Expression.Constant(prev))).Compile()();
  }
  class A
  {
    public int P1;
  }
  class B
  {
    public int P1;
  }

  var a = new A();
  var b = new B();
  AssignAndDoSomething(a.P1, b.P1, () => b.P1 == a.P1);
```